# boost asio and WinSock.h has already been included

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, wxwidgets

Like many people who have used the Boost ASIO library, I'm getting the "WinSock.h has already been included" error.  In the other posts, the question was answered by moving the #include  line above the #include

In my case, I'm working on a project that is using Wx Widgets and seems to not have any connections to MFC, or direct connections to Win32. I haven't been able to find any calls to windows.h, nor anything related. I've also tried using WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN and BOOST_ASIO_NO_WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN declarations.

I'm wondering if anyone writing a Wx Widgets project has run into a similar problem with Boost ASIO? If so, were you able to work around the Winsock error?

Comment: Including wxwidgets headers will almost certainly pull in `winsock.h`, so move your ASIO includes above any wxwidgets includes.

Comment: I have also seen this when one header pulls in winsock2.h and another pulls in winsock.h.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I have placed the ASIO includes above the wxwidgets (thinking the windows.h calls were buried there), but I haven't had any luck so far.  I'll have to see what the wx files are including.  Perhaps my problem is there?  Thank you both.

Answer (score 8):

I have a solution.  The steps to fixing this is to define the WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN in side of the project's settings.

Go to Project->Properties, Select C/C++->Preprocessor

Under Preprocessor Definitions, add WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN.

The mistake I was making before was to add a #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN to the code files. This didn't help anything. Note, my #include  is still set above the WxWidget includes.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `wxUSE_IPV6` to 1 or, alternatively, setting `wxUSE_SOCKETS` to 0 in your `include/wx/msw/setup.h` file should fix the problem -- either by including WinSock2 headers if you do the former or not including WinSock ones neither if you do the latter.

Don't forget to rebuild your wxWidgets library if you do either change!

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this.  I will check this out.